# Copying row to new sheet and repeat the code until end of row in input sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using below code for copying Rows from Sheet 1, Sheet 2 & Sheet 3 to final Sheet.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details")

    For i = 2 To shSource.Cells(10, 6).Value
        j = 3
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Final").Rows(j): j = j + 1
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Final").Rows(j): j = j + 1
        Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Final").Rows(j): j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

There are 20 Rows in Sheet 1, Sheet 2 & Sheet 3 which need to be copied to final Sheet one by one.
But in above code only Last Row of each Sheet is being copied to final sheet i.e. Row no. 20 of all sheets.

Can anybody help me and let me know where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `j = 3` right before your `For` loop

Comment: @L42 As I'm new to this site I was not aware how to accept the answer. I will do the same. Thanks